# Is there syntax for a PDF indirect object to just refer to another object?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I'm being sent PDFs with hundreds of duplicate images which are causing trouble downstream. That is, everything between e.g. `25 0 obj` and `endobj` is byte for byte identical, including the dictionary and stream. I've written a script to confirm this.

The system processing these PDFs can't easily have new software installed, and nothing we have seems to detect and merge these (`ghostscript`, `pdftk`, etc). If possible I'd like to write my own `perl` script to edit these objects so that they refer to a previous object instead. This is so I don't need to decompress and parse content streams and update all the references to these objects after stripping the duplicate objects, which would be a lot harder to guarantee.

I am thinking something like the below:

```
25 0 obj
15 0 R
endobj
```

But I don't know the syntax, or if it even exists.

I am aware I will need to preserve or update `xref` offsets, that's not a problem I've done it before. I'm also aware this isn't a great idea for a generalised solution and libraries may exist to help, but I'm taking this as an exercise to learn more about the PDF spec.

Comment: Have you tried your proposal? It should work in most cases.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work. Ghostscript says "Warning: Ignoring non-dictionary /XObject attribute while checking for transparency." so I assume it's a parsing error because there is no dictionary. I am not sure what needs to be added or whether anything can be to fix this.

Comment: Hmm. I actually don't see in the specification that your construction would be forbidden.

Comment: Perhaps I am going about this the wrong way, and parsing the XObject dictionary to replace references (like /Image1 8 0 R) is the best way forward. AFAIK this will capture all references without parsing streams. I'll try next time I'm in the office.